# Rust sorting uses surprisingly few comparaisons

Tags: sorting, rust

I am currently learning Rust (using the Rust book), and [one page](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-01-closures.html) mentions counting the number of times the sorting key was used while sorting an array. I modified the code in order to count this for arbitrary sizes, and here is the code :

```
fn main() {
    const MAX: i32 = 10000;
    for n in 1..MAX {
        let mut v: Vec<i32> = (1..n).collect();
        let mut ops = 0;
        
        v.sort_by(|x, y| {
            ops += 1;
            x.cmp(y)
        });
        
        if n-2 >= 0 {
            assert_eq!(n-2, ops);
        }
        // println!("A list of {n} elements is sorted in {ops} operations");

    }
}
```

However, it seems that in order to sort a vector of n elements, Rust only needs n-2 comparaisons (the code above runs without panicking).
How can this be possible ? Aren't sorts supposed to be in O(n*log(n)) ?
Is it because Rust somehow "noticed" that my input vector was already sorted ?

Even in that case, how can a vector of length 2 can be sorted without any comparaisons ? Shouldn't it at least be n-1 ?

Comment: First, the time complexity is in the worst case. And then, you can read into [merge_sort](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/slice.rs.html#330-332)  source code to learn how it works actually. Most sort-like APIs are invoking this function.

Comment: Your input is misleading you, it represents the best case time complexity, which is an already sorted array, regarding your comparator.

Comment: You can try [shuffling](https://docs.rs/rand/latest/rand/seq/trait.SliceRandom.html#tymethod.shuffle) the data before sorting it.

Comment: @Finomnis Sorry I may not make it clearer, according to [the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/slice.rs.html#1079), that O(n*log(n)) ,means `The invariants ensure that the total running time is *O*(*n* \* log(*n*)) worst-case`. I should have said **that time complexity in the docs** is in the worst case.

Comment: I think I have made it clear, and I definitely referred to what you said "only one part of time complexity" in the context. The conversation below is precise enough to understand it. If you please, help edit the question itself to be more precise & concise.

Comment: *EDT*: First, the O(n*log(n)) mentioned above is in the worst-case time complexity of `slice::merge_sort`. And then, you can read into [`slice::merge_sort`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/slice.rs.html#334) source code to learn how it works actually. Most sort-like APIs are invoking this function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The biggest misconseption you have, I think, is:

```rust
fn main() {
    const SIZE: i32 = 5;
    let v: Vec<i32> = (1..SIZE).collect();
    println!("{}", v.len());
}
```

```
4
```

The range `1..SIZE` does not include `SIZE` and contains `SIZE-1` elements.
Further, it will already be sorted, so it's as simple as iterating through it once.

See here:

```rust
fn main() {
    const SIZE: i32 = 5;

    let mut v: Vec<i32> = (1..SIZE).collect();
    let mut ops = 0;

    v.sort_by(|x, y| {
        ops += 1;
        let result = x.cmp(y);
        println!(" - cmp {} vs {} => {:?}", x, y, result);
        result
    });

    println!("Total comparisons: {}", ops);
}
```

```
 - cmp 4 vs 3 => Greater
 - cmp 3 vs 2 => Greater
 - cmp 2 vs 1 => Greater
Total comparisons: 3
```

---

> it seems that in order to sort a vector of n elements, Rust only needs n-2 comparaisons

That is incorrect. In order to sort an **already sorted** vector (which yours are), Rust needs `n-1` comparisons. It doesn't *detect* that, that's just an inherent property of the mergesort implementation that Rust uses.

If it isn't already sorted, it will be more:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<i32> = vec![2, 4, 1, 3];

    let mut ops = 0;

    v.sort_by(|x, y| {
        ops += 1;
        let result = x.cmp(y);
        println!(" - cmp {} vs {} => {:?}", x, y, result);
        result
    });

    println!("Total comparisons: {}", ops);
}
```

```
 - cmp 3 vs 1 => Greater
 - cmp 1 vs 4 => Less
 - cmp 3 vs 4 => Less
 - cmp 1 vs 2 => Less
 - cmp 3 vs 2 => Greater
Total comparisons: 5
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI [`sort_by`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/slice.rs.html#330-332):

```rust
    pub fn sort_by<F>(&mut self, mut compare: F)
    where
        F: FnMut(&T, &T) -> Ordering,
    {
        merge_sort(self, |a, b| compare(a, b) == Less);
    }
```

and it actually invokes [`merge_sort`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/slice.rs.html#1081):

```rust
/// This merge sort borrows some (but not all) ideas from TimSort, which is described in detail
/// [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/listsort.txt).
///
/// The algorithm identifies strictly descending and non-descending subsequences, which are called
/// natural runs. There is a stack of pending runs yet to be merged. Each newly found run is pushed
/// onto the stack, and then some pairs of adjacent runs are merged until these two invariants are
/// satisfied:
///
/// 1. for every `i` in `1..runs.len()`: `runs[i - 1].len > runs[i].len`
/// 2. for every `i` in `2..runs.len()`: `runs[i - 2].len > runs[i - 1].len + runs[i].len`
///
/// The invariants ensure that the total running time is *O*(*n* \* log(*n*)) worst-case.
#[cfg(not(no_global_oom_handling))]
fn merge_sort<T, F>(v: &mut [T], mut is_less: F)
```

> how can a vector of length 2 be sorted without any comparisons? Shouldn't it at least be n-1?

`(1..2)` returns a slice of length 1 (start from 1, but less than 2). So, when `n == 2` in your code, please note that the length of the vector is one.

Let me demonstrate how it will actually go in the `merge_sort` if the input is a slice shorter than or equal to 2.

```rust
    // MAX_INSERTION: 20
    if len <= MAX_INSERTION {
        // if the len is less than 1, it won't use `is_less` closure to let you count the cmp.
        if len >= 2 {
            for i in (0..len - 1).rev() {
                insert_head(&mut v[i..], &mut is_less); // <- go into `insert_head`.
            }
        }
        return;
    }
```

```rust
fn insert_head<T, F>(v: &mut [T], is_less: &mut F)
where
    F: FnMut(&T, &T) -> bool,
{
    if v.len() >= 2 && is_less(&v[1], &v[0]) // <- here it uses the closure to make comparison.
```

So if your input is less than 21, short arrays will get sorted in place via insertion sort to avoid allocations.